# Search and Copy Excel Data with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA program to search through a large spreadsheet and copy rows that have the same account five or more times associated with the data to a different sheet. The program does exactly what it's supposed to do when I step through each individual line (F8), but when I run the program (F5), it doesn't end up copying any information to the second sheet. I've tried adding a two second delay between switching sheets and pasting the data, just in case this was the problem, but so far it hasn't helped.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I thought that the screen updating might be causing the problem, so I disabled it. The program still didn't paste the data in the other worksheet.

Second Edit: I noticed that when I put a stop in at the beginning of the while loop and step the program through in chunks, it also does not copy and paste the data like it should be. It still works when stepping through individual lines of code, though. I also removed the 2 second pauses as those didn't make a difference.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub Main()
Worksheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("C2").Select
AcctName = ActiveCell.Value
LoopControl = 0
AcctNameCt = 1
CurrentAcctRow = ActiveCell.Row

Do While LoopControl <> 1

    SecondLoopControl = 0
    If AcctName = ActiveCell.Offset(AcctNameCt, 0).Value Then
        AcctNameCt = AcctNameCt + 1
        If AcctNameCt > 4 Then
        GreaterThanFour
        End If
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(AcctNameCt, 0).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(AcctNameCt, 0).Activate
        AcctName = ActiveCell.Value
        AcctNameCt = 1
        CurrentAcctRow = ActiveCell.Row
    End If
Loop
End Sub

Public Sub CopyData()
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim StopCopy As Integer
    Dim RestartRow As Integer
    EndRow = CurrentAcctRow + AcctNameCt
    StopCopy = EndRow - 1
    RestartRow = EndRow + 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & CurrentAcctRow & ":" & "C" & StopCopy).EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    LookForEmptyRow
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial
    CurrentAcctRow = CurentAcctRow + 1
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("C" & EndRow).Select
    AcctNameCt = 0

End Sub

Public Sub GreaterThanFour()
    Do While SecondLoopControl <> 1
        If AcctName = ActiveCell.Offset(AcctNameCt, 0).Value Then
            AcctNameCt = AcctNameCt + 1
        Else
            CopyData
            SecondLoopControl = 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub LookForEmptyRow()
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim LookAnotherLoopControl As Integer
    LookAnotherLoopControl = 0
    Do While LookAnotherLoopControl <> 1
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub Else ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the worksheet names to variables and called those, rather than calling the worksheets directly. For some reason, this works better.

```
 Set wbA = Workbooks(Workbook Name)
 Set wsA = Worksheets(Worksheet Name 1)
 Set wsB = Worksheets(Worksheet Name 2)
```

Where the "Workbook Name" and "Worksheet Name 1" reflect the actual names, instead. Those are working better than:

```
Worksheets(2).Activate
LookForEmptyRow
ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial
CurrentAcctRow = CurentAcctRow + 1
Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("C" & EndRow).Select
```

I also used a better method to look for an empty row, rather than writing my own subroutine. The original code had this sub that I wrote:

```
 Public Sub LookForEmptyRow()
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim LookAnotherLoopControl As Integer
    LookAnotherLoopControl = 0
    Do While LookAnotherLoopControl <> 1
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub Else ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
```

Which, while effective, was highly inefficient. I replaced it with the much more efficient line of code:

```
lRow = Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lRow + 1, 1).Activate
```